# AVPlayer runs on simulator but not real device

Tags: ios, swift, video

In my application, I want to play a local video on my real device. I am using my system WiFi hotspot to connect the network to my device.

This code runs on the simulator perfectly, but not on a real device.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import  AVFoundation
class SafaribroserViewController: UIViewController {

        var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        var playerView = AVPlayer()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }


        @IBAction func hsdgfsf(_ sender: Any) {
            let fileURL = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/Volumes/E/adam/small.mp4")
            playerView = AVPlayer(url: fileURL as URL)
            playerViewController.player = playerView
            present(playerViewController,animated:true) {
                self.playerViewController.player?.play()
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: In real device your URL may be changed that's why video is not played. You can not do like this Hard code URL.

Comment: Thanks,  if I can`t  give the path like this so how can I? I know the IP of the local server and  file location

Comment: You can store video on server and retrive url of it. OR You can store video in document directory in device with making a folder then you can access path within that folder.

Comment: I don't want to do throw the server and I don't know how to retrieve from document directory.

Comment: Search for it. You can get answer from StackOverflow easily

Comment: On your iOS device there is no `/Volumes` folder. You need to load the file via HTTP

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you.

```
  import UIKit
  import AVKit
  import AVFoundation

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var player = AVPlayer()
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    playVideo()
}

func playVideo() {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myvideo", ofType:"m4v") 
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
  }
}
```